# Selenium doesn't seem to work even though geckodriver is in /usr/local/bin/

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver, geckodriver

I'm using Python 2.7 and, since I want to program a simple auto-login bot, I've installed Selenium and Geckodriver. After looking around on the Internet (here too), I put the Geckodriver executable in `/usr/local/bin`. Now, when I try to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in __init__
keep_alive=True)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 98, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 188, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

Why is that and how should I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you try to update your Firefox? This issue usaly happens with old versions.

Comment: I feel really dumb, to think it was this easy... it works now, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to add a point:-)